# Load content in Primefaces Extensions documentViewer

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I'm loading StreamedContent into the document viewer like this.

**xhtml:**

```
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton value="Content A" action="#{viewer.selectContentA()}" update="viewerForm" />
        <p:commandButton value="Content B" action="#{viewer.selectContentB()}" update="viewerForm" />
    </h:form>
    <h:form id="viewerForm">
        <pe:documentViewer value="#{viewer.content}" download="demo.pdf" height="500"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

**Bean:**

```
public void selectContentA() {
    content = contentA;
}
public void selectContentB() {
    content = contentB;
}
public StreamedContent getContent() {
    return content;
}
```

**Question:**
Is there any way to change the document in the viewer without update the whole component?

Comment: What is the problem with updating the 'whole' component?

Comment: The problem is that this becomes anoying if you open a new document whereas the rest of the page stays static. I'm looking for a solution to make it work more smootly, just like on the showcase when you switch between "Url", "Resource" and "StreamedContent" https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/documentviewer/basic.jsf So I want the viewer to stay as it is and just update its content.

Comment: In the showcase you switch to three different tabs. You can always use something similar. Define 2 viewers, load one, click a button, load the other in the background and when done, switch 'viewer' via javascript. And you can look in the source to see if there is a javascript API to switch document (the viewer IS based on the Mozilla pdf.js, so lots of info)

Comment: The Documentviewer uses an iFrame to load the content dynamically from your streamed source.  I don't think there is a way to just update the content of the viewer the way it works currently.  it creates a dynamic.xhtml document to load your stream content in and pass to the Document Viewer.

Comment: @Melloware Should I create a feature-ticket for this or would that be futile? As far as I know, pdf.js supports this and you saying "the way it works currently" makes me curious if there is a chance that the component will support this feature someday.

Comment: Would it change anything regarding the issue if I fetch the document from an URL instead of using a streamed source or more precisely simplify using of the pdf.js API?

Comment: Yes please create an issue I will see if I can fix it or maybe add something to alleviate it.  As far a using a URL goes, you can do View Source and see the iFrame URL.  If you use clever jquery you can just change the URL and theoretically it should reload.

Comment: https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions.github.com/issues/605

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using:

```
function refresh() {
     document.getElementById('viewerForm:viewer').contentDocument.location.reload();
}
<p:commandButton value="Load document" ... oncomplete="refresh()" />
```

instead of

```
<p:commandButton` value="Load document" ...  update="viewerForm:viewer" />
```

works for me.